# How to use Type.GetType in a expression lambda

Tags: c#

I'm trying do the next instruction in c#:

```
Form form = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Type.GetType("MyFormName"));
```

But i have a error: **Method name expected.**

What would be the correct usage of the instruction.

Comment: If this question is about the particular error message, it is not related to lambda expressions - in that case, you should reduce the problem to something like `bool a = x is Type.GetType("MyFormName");`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have a `Type` instance you need to use `IsAssignableFrom` instead of `is`:

```
x => Type.GetType("MyFormName").IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())
```

This of course assumes that you really can't reference the actual type at compile time.  If you can, then you could instead simplify this code to:

```
.OfType<MyFormName>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Which is going to have something internally that resembles:

```
x is MyFormName
```

Which is how the `is` operator is designed to be used.